# Compute Rank of an Entity in Objectify

Tags: java, entity, ranking, objectify

My goal is to compute the absolute rank of an entity based on some attribute provided as a string. The basic approach I am using is to issue a query, sort its results in descending order and count all those results which are greater than the attribute value of my particular entity. The query looks something like this

```
int rank = o.query(Entity.class).order(String.format("-%s",attribute)).
           .filter(String.format("%s >", attribute), something).count();
```

However, something is the part where I am stuck. As far as I understand the concepts of objectify, querying for specific entity members is out of the question. My next step would either be to use an (ugly but fast in terms of dev time) if-construct to identify the particular entity member, or start using reflection (a bit less ugly, but slow in terms of dev time).

Either way, I am left with the feeling that I miss some obvious and/or elegant way to accomplish this task. Any suggestions? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want the first entity and you want the count of remaining entities?  There are two ways to do this:

1. Use two queries.  Use `limit(1)` on the >= one that will return the first entity.  Start it first, but don't materialize the result so that it runs asynchronously in parallel with the second.
2. Instead of `count()`, run a keys-only query with >=.  Keep the first key to do a fetch, and count the rest manually.  Keys-only queries cost the same (small ops per count) as count() queries because count() queries are essentially the same thing under the covers.

I would probably go with #2.  Either way, I hope that your counts are not large because otherwise you will churn through a *lot* of small datastore ops and your app will be expensive!

Comment: Sorry, my description might have been a bit misleading. My goal is to compute the absolute rank of a given entity, to allow statements like: "according to attribute 'a', my entity here is n-th". My solution was using reflection to determine the attributes value to filter for and then a query as above. To increase performance, I went with your suggestion to run a keys only query, followed by manually counting the keys. Works like a charm, thx :).